# Ansible file copy with src depending on whether a path exists

Tags: ansible

Let's say I have a task to distribute a standard `/etc/aliases` file.

```
- name: Distribute /etc/aliases
  copy:
      src:   generic/etc/aliases
      dest:  /etc/aliases
      owner: root
      group: root
      mode:  0644
```

But I would like to have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
site.yml
roles/
    common/
        files/
            fqdn/
                foo.example.com/
                    etc/
                        aliases
            generic/
                etc/
                    aliases
        tasks/
            main.yml
            etc_aliases.yml
```

Then, if (and only if) the file `fqdn/{{ inventory_hostname }}/etc/aliases` exists, copy that, otherwise copy the file `generic/etc/aliases` instead. So, the choice of which file to copy is based solely on whether the file exists or not; by creating the `fqdn/foo.example.com/etc/aliases` file, host foo.example.com gets that one instead of the generic one.

Is that a sensible thing to want to do in Ansible and if so how would I accomplish it? If not, what is the correct pattern for this sort of thing?

I realise that I can do it by setting a variable for the source path and overriding it on a per-host basis. For me the downside with this approach is that the host variable gets set in a place far away from the role definition, and also that it requires a variable setting *and* a file being placed, whereas the way I'd like to do it requires just a file being placed inside the role directory tree.

I also found I could do it by using the stat module, to check if the source file path with the host name in does exist first, but I didn't find a way there to do it without having two copy tasks, one with a `when: blah.stat.exists defined` and the other with a `when: blah.stat.exists not defined` for the copy of the generic file. It also then lists three tasks in the output: one for the stat and then one for each of the possible copies, which seems a bit verbose.

Is there a way to do what I want or is there a better way to accomplish a similar outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, looks like I am able to do it with a loop that finds first matched:

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#finding-first-matched-files

```
- name: Define contents of /etc/aliases
  copy:
      src:   "{{ item }}"
      dest:  /etc/aliases
      owner: root
      group: root
      mode:  0644
  with_first_found:
      - fqdn/{{ inventory_hostname }}/etc/aliases
      - generic/etc/aliases
```

I spent hours searching for something like this but it seems I did not use the correct search terms until just now!